# Chrome Extension Refused to Load because it violates the following Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load a Chrome Extension with React, but I keep getting the following error:

> Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3, 
  "name": "Reminder-App",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Reminder app for all your tasks",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Reminder App"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://www.google.com/*"
  ]
}
```

Index.html

```
 <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
```

Comment: ManifestV3 doesn't allow remote scripts. Download jquery and include it within the extension.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:reactjs] (and have "with React" in the opening sentence) when your code *isn't* loading React and is loading jQuery (which you typically don't need in React pages).

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/#remotely-hosted-code):

> **Remotely hosted code**
>
> A key security improvement in Manifest V3 is that **extensions can't load remote code like JavaScript** or Wasm files. This lets us more reliably and efficiently review the safe behavior of extensions when they're submitted to the Chrome Web Store. Specifically, all logic must be included in the extension's package.

*(my emphasis)*